# Connecting to postgres database with Node.js

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am running the following command from my command line

```
npm models/database.js
```

I am getting the error:

```
password authentication failed for user "marco"
```

this is my connection code and its stored in my Database.js file within my models folder at the root level of my project.

```
var pg = require('pg');
// var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/NodeTestProject';
var connectionString = "postgres://marco:Easye123@localhost:5432/NodeTestProject";

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE users(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName VARCHAR(40) not null, LastName VARCHAR(40) not null, MiddleName VARCHAR(40) not null, Email VARCHAR(40) not null, UserName VARCHAR(40) not null, Password VARCHAR(40) not null');
query.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
```

I am 100% sure that when I set up Postgresql I set the password to "Easye123" I can log in to Postgresql no issues and I have created a database called NodeTestProject. Do i have to create a user for the NodeTestProject database? Am I missing a step? Any feedback would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seems like this would be mostly unrelated to node.js

Comment: This  a Node.Js project using Postgresql thanks for your very helpful feedback. @KevinB

Comment: My point is if node.js can't connect to it due to a permissions issue, you should have the same problem from the console using the same user information. If you don't, then more research needs to be done.

Comment: Once again thank you for the useful feedback @KevinB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whoever is new to Postgresql

The credentials you put on your connection file are not the same as the SuperUser you set up while installing Postgresql. Within your pgAdminIII you must create a Group Role and allow that Group Role to "Can Login" once that is set up declare the owner of the Database as that Group Role User. Finally declare that GroupRole user as the username and the password you used for it as the password in your connection string.

[image]

[image]

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://Marco:12345@localhost:5432/NodeTestProject";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].theTime);
    //output: Tue Jan 15 2013 19:12:47 GMT-600 (CST)
    client.end();
  });
});
```

I can now successfully log into this local database and interact with it.